# Why are there duplicated debug targets?

Tags: visual-studio

Why are there duplicated debug targets? I use FF most of the time but I also test in Chrome; I almost never use Edge. This is from VS 2019 Community.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple channels of these browsers installed (e.g. dev/canary/preview/nightly/etc versions)?

If so, that would likely explain it.

If not, what kind of project is this? I can investigate further.

Comment: No multiple channels. .NET Framework 4.6, web forms. Currently VS 2019 Community, but I *think* I've noticed this many times over the years in different versions of VS (pretty sure, but not positive). It doesn't seem to affect anything negatively.

Comment: Interesting. If you [report a problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio it'll create a feedback ticket. If you then link it here, I can make sure it gets sent to the right team internally.

Comment: I reported, but it all happened inside VS and I was not informed of a ticket #, or anything else. 2021-09-06 18:09 or 18:10. I included a link to this question.

Comment: I would have expected you to be taken to a web page on Developer Community. The link to that page would suffice as the ticket. Searching by time will be tricky, but I'll give it a go. What time zone are you in?

Comment: Eastern time zone. Don't go out of your way.